# How to get the array value and object key values match irrespective of the order

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

In an array of value

```
var legends =['some','key', 'value'];
```

a graph with the respective obj values;

```
var graph = {
  orgid: ['123', '123556', '456', '345', '2345'],
  some: [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],
  key: [900, 900, 900, 900, 900],
  value: [1072, 1373, 946, 715, 276]
 };
```

I wanted to extract the graph with only key values mentioned in an array to be inserted into another array

I have executed the code but it only works if the order of the keys which are the same in the order mentioned in the obj

**es5 way**

```
var grphFilter = [];
var countRaw = 0; 
for (var key in graph) {
  if (key === legends[count] ) {
    grphFilter.push(graph[key]);
    count++;
  }
}
```

**es6 way**

```
let grphFilter = [];
let count = 0; 
const result = Object.entries(graph).forEach(function([key, value]) {
  if (key === legends[count]) {
    grphFilter.push(value);
    count++
  }
})
```

but it won't work for the keys which are not in order like.

```
var legendsNotOrder =['key', 'some', 'value'];
```

irrespective of the order of the value in the legends array, the result should be the final result, be it `legends` or `legendsNotOrder`

Final Result

```
var graphfiltered = [
  [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],
  [900, 900, 900, 900, 900],
  [1072, 1373, 946, 715, 276]
];
```

Comment: The structure of `graphfiltered` is different (it's an array) from your `graph` (plain object). What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Instead of `if (key === legends[count])` you want to check if `key` is a key in the `legends` array

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through the array and get only the desired property values from object.

```js
var legends =['some','key', 'value'];

var graph = {orgid: ['123', '123556', '456', '345', '2345'],some: [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],key: [900, 900, 900, 900, 900],value: [1072, 1373, 946, 715, 276]};
 
let filteredGraph = legends.map( cur => graph[cur])

console.log(filteredGraph)


//In case you have keys in legend which are not available in graph you can use below code

let filteredGraph = legends.filter( cur => graph[cur])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I had to use a filter to removed undefined if there are more values in the legends array

Comment: @SwapnilSrivastava My answer cover that case and only loops once on the `legends` array, you could give it a try if you like.

Comment: @SwapnilSrivastava i considered what you said in question. anyway you can see the updated one. you just need to change map to filter

Answer (score 1):

Use Object#entries, Array#reduce, Array#includes, Array#push

```js
const legends=['some','key','value'];const graph={orgid:['123','123556','456','345','2345'],some:[1500,1500,1500,1500,1500],key:[900,900,900,900,900],value:[1072,1373,946,715,276]}

const res = Object.entries(graph)
.reduce((a,[k,v])=>{
  if(legends.includes(k)) a.push(v);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Don't use `reduce` with `push`. Use `map` and `filter` instead.

Comment: @Bergi and why not?

Comment: I think it's because the essence of the function is that you are "reducing"  multiple values to one value, whereas here you are accumulating with `push()`

Comment: Because higher-level functions are easier to understand than primitive ones. Why did you use `reduce` instead of a simple `for` loop?

Comment: @Bergi I think that's quite subjective. However, I agree that from a beginner point of view it can be *more* complex (depending on your background). I've recently gave lessons to first year undergraduates on javascript basics (they have not had the opportunity to code in any other language; meaning they had not seen simple `for` syntax and/or callbacks). Some of them understood simple `for` loops better than `reduce`, `map`, etc while others not. When I give a solution in javascript, I will always opt for a feature using an es6 feature before `for`.

Comment: @RobertRocha I see your point of view, however even if I'm using `push` I'm still reducing the number of results found in `graph`.

Comment: @kemicofa I meant that `map` is objectively higher-level than `reduce`.

Comment: @kemicofa If you wanted to go for the "basic" style, then you should have used `for` with `push`. (Which fits better in an imperative loop, as it mutates the array). It's also a line shorter than the `reduce`.

Comment: @Bergi if I decided to use `map` I would first have to use `filter`. I'd essentially be looping twice through. In my personal opinion, I'll use the solution that I think works best.  I appreciate your feedback. If you don't agree with my solution then feel free to downvote. Even if I *should* (subjective once again) use `for`, I'll use es6 features if I can.

Comment: By using `Object.entries()`, you already are looping twice - I don't think that matters when we discuss elegance :-)

Comment: Also using map and filter is more functional/declarative/semantic way of programming. If i read your code, i know map and filter as more meaningfull and i need not to read low level details. push is low level and without understanding whole context, i wont know what is push used for.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the array with the `keys`, then access directly the `graph` object. Also, you can check if key is `valid` before doing the `push` on the new array:

```js
var legends = ['some', 'key', 'value', 'notkey'];

var graph = {
    orgid: ['123', '123556', '456', '345', '2345'],
    some: [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],
    key: [900, 900, 900, 900, 900],
    value: [1072, 1373, 946, 715, 276]
 };
 
 let graphFilter = [];
 legends.forEach(x => graph[x] && graphFilter.push(graph[x]));
 console.log(graphFilter);
```

Another alternative is to combine [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the graph's entries.

```js
var legends = ['some', 'key', 'value', 'notkey'];

var graph = {
    orgid: ['123', '123556', '456', '345', '2345'],
    some: [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],
    key: [900, 900, 900, 900, 900],
    value: [1072, 1373, 946, 715, 276]
 };
 
let graphFilter = Object.entries(graph)
     .filter(([k, v]) => legends.includes(k))
     .map(([k, v]) => v);

console.log(graphFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you check the `key` at the current iteration with a specific value in the `legends` array. What you need to check is if the `key` at the current iteration is equal to any of the value of this array.

Something like:

```
legends.includes(key)
```

Here is a complete example:

```js
var legends = ['some', 'key', 'value'];

var graph = {
  orgid: ['123', '123556', '456', '345', '2345'],
  some: [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],
  key: [900, 900, 900, 900, 900],
  value: [1072, 1373, 946, 715, 276]
};

var graphFilter = [];
for (var key in graph) {
  if (legends.includes(key)) {
    graphFilter[legends.indexOf(key)] = graph[key];
  }
}

console.log(graphFilter);
```

Comment: After the `var key in graph` why not just do `if(key in graph) graphFilter.push(graph[key]);` ?

Comment: @RobertRocha To keep the order, the OP seems to want that.

Answer (score 0):

**ES6** One loop solution with `reduce` that ignores unknown keys in a `legends` array:

```js
const legends = ['some', 'key', 'value', 'random_key'];

const graph = {
    orgid: ['123', '123556', '456', '345', '2345'],
    some:  [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],
    key:   [900, 900, 900, 900, 900],
    value: [1072, 1373, 946, 715, 276]
};

const result = legends.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (r = graph[c]) {
        a.push(r);
    }
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

In general, `map` + `filter` are often replaceable with `reduce`. The concern, the code may become more complicated. The benefit would probably be an optimisation (probably "micro"), which often is not worth it.

Please note, I replaced `var` with `const` in your original code.